# Function chooseint in Rng library in Scala

Tags: scala, random

These functions are from [Rng.scala](https://github.com/NICTA/rng/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/nicta/rng/Rng.scala). Function `int` generates pseudorandom 32 bits. Function `chooseint` does not like `nextInt(n: Int)` of `java.util.Random`, which does the similar thing.

```
def int: Rng[Int] = nextbits(32)

def chooseint(l: Int, h: Int): Rng[Int] =
  int map (x => {
    val (ll, hh) = if(h < l) (h, l) else (l, h)
    // using longs to avoid overflows
    val diff = hh.toLong - ll.toLong
    if (diff == 0) ll
    else           (ll.toLong + (math.abs(x.toLong) % (diff + 1))).toInt
  })
```

Does `chooseint` really generate uniformly distributed pseudorandom for `l = 0` and `h > 0` ?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. You could confirm this by testing with e.g. `l=0, h = (INT_MAX * 2) / 3` - I predict you'd see twice as many numbers below `INT_MAX/3` as above that.

Comment: Thanks. It is unfortunate that such a good library is not useful in  practice. Maybe it can be fixed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and the reason is that the range of the random numbers is not always evenly divisible by `(diff + 1)`. It's quite well documented in [the Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).